# Design pattern for database manager class

Tags: java, database, design-patterns

I implemented a class `Database Manager` that manages operations on two database engines. The class has a private variable `databaseEngine` which is set before using class methods (drop database, create database, run script, compare, disconnect, etc.) and based on this variable the class recognizes how to behave.

However, and I know it's wrong,  `Database Manager`'s methods are full of switch cases like this one:

```
public void CreateNewDatabase(String databaseName){

switch (databaseEngine){
  case "mysql":
      //Executes a prepared statement for dropping mysql database (databaseName
  break;
  case "postgres":
      //Executes a prepared statement for dropping postgres database (databaseName
  break;
...
    }
}
```

I require a good advice about this. I want to load everything from configuration and resources folders, I mean, the prepared statement for creating and dropping, etc. If a new database engine needs to be supported, it won't be a headache as It would just require to save sql sripts in a resources file and any other data in a configuration file. **Please, suggest me any design pattern useful for this case.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you need to invoke different operations based on a switch statement, think about using an abstract class which defines the operation interface and implementation classes which implement the operation.

In your case `databaseEngine` is a String which names a database. Instead create an abstract class `DatabaseEngine` and define operations like `createDatabase`:

```
 public abstract class DatabaseEngine {
      public abstract void createDatabase(String databaseName);
      public abstract void dropDatabase(String databaseName);
 }
```

and add implementations:

```
public class PostgresEngine extends DatabaseEngine {
     public void createDatabase(String databaseName) { 
         ... // do it the postgres way
     }   
}
```

and then use it in your manager class

```
public void createNewDatabase(String databaseName) {
     engine_.createDatabase(databaseName);
}
```

Comment: But I want to avoid having engine specific classes. Just a single class and load everything from properties. This way, I wouldn't need to touch the code when a new database engine needs to be supported

Comment: @Venom then create property files for each engine, and store command patterns for each supported operation, and replace variables in those patterns with actual values at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

First thing: switching on strings is so old school; if at all; you would want to use a true enum for that. But of course, that isn't really the point; and switching over enums is as bad as switching over strings (regarding the thing that you have in mind) from a "OO design" point of view.

The solution by wero is definitely the "correct choice" from an OO perspective. You see, good OO design starts with [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)); and SOLID starts with [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

In this case, I would point out the "there is only one reason to change" aspect of SRP. Thing is: if you push **all** database handling for 2, 3, n different databases into one class ... that means that you have to change that one class if any of your databases requires a change. Besides the obvious: providing "access means" to ONE database is (almost more) than enough of a "single responsibility" for a single class.

Another point of view: this is about balancing. Either you are interested in a good, well structured, "really OO type of" design ... then you have to bite the bullet and either define an interface or abstract base class; that is then implemented/extended differently for each concrete database.

Or you prefer "stuffing everything into one class" ... then just keep what you have, because it really doesn't matter if you use door handles made out of gold or steel ... for a house that was built on a bad basement anyway.

Meaning: your switch statements are just the result of a less-than-optimal design. Now decide if you want to cure the symptom or the root cause of the problem.

Comment: So, true. I didn't see your answer when I was typing mine. Agree on `switching on strings` but it's not really a problem as you mentioned in your answer. SRP violation is.

Answer (score 1):

> I implemented a class Database Manager that manages operations on two database engines.

What if you had three or four or five different databases/storages? For example, Oracle, MongoDB, Redis, etc. Would you still put implementation for all of them into `Database Manager`?

> Database Manager's methods are full of switch cases...

As expected, because you put everything into one class.

> Please, suggest me any design pattern useful for this case.

The most straitforward way to simplify your solution would be to separate `MySQL` and `Postgree` implementations from each other. You would need to use *Factory* and *Strategy* design patterns. If one sees a switch, one should consider using them, but don't be obsessed with patterns. They are NOT your goal, i.e. don't put them everywhere in your code just because you can.

So, you should start from defining your abstractions. Create an interface or an abstract class if there's a functionality common to all database subclasses.

```
// I'm not sure what methods you need, so I just added methods you mentioned.
public interface MyDatabase {
    void drop();
    void create();
    void runScript();
    void compare();
    void disconnect();
}
```

Then you need to implement your *databases* which in fact are *strategies*.

```
public final class MySqlDatabase implements MyDatabase {
    @Override
    public void drop() {}
    ...
}

public final class PostgreDatabase implements MyDatabase {
    @Override
    public void drop() {}
    ...
}
```

Finally you need to create a *factory*. You can make it static or implement an interface if you like.

```
public class MyDatabaseFactory {
    public MyDatabase create(String type) {
        switch (type) {
        case "mysql":
            return new MySqlDatabase();
        case "postgress":
            return new PostgreDatabase();
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    } 
}
```

You don't necessarily have to pass a string. It can be an option/settings class, but they have a tendency to grow which may lead to bloated classes. But don't worry too much about it, it's not your biggest problem at the moment.

Last, but not least. If you don't mind, revise your naming conventions. Please, [don't name your classes as managers or helpers](http://www.yegor256.com/2015/03/09/objects-end-with-er.html).

Comment: Great answer! Very much to the point, excellent examples!

Answer (score 0):

You could create an abstract base class for your DatabaseEngines like this:

```
public abstract class DatabaseEngine {

    public abstract void createDatabase(final String databaseName);

    public abstract void dropDatabase(final String databaseName);
}
```

And then create concrete implementations for each DatabaseEngine you are supporting:

```
public final class MySQLEngine extends DatabaseEngine {

    @Override
    public void createDatabase(final String databaseName) {
    }

    @Override
    public void dropDatabase(final String databaseName) {
    }
}
```

Then when you want to make a call to create/drop it will look more like this:

```
databaseEngine.createDatabase("whatever");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is opinion based question: but in my point of view you can use:

1. [Factory Design pattern.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm) This will take care of any other
   database added or changed in future.

---

Example:

```
public interface IDataBaseEngine {
    ...
}

public class OracleDBConnection implements IDataBaseEngine {
    ...
}

public class MySQLDBConnection implements IDataBaseEngine {
    ....
}

public class DatabaseEngineFactory {
    public IDataBaseEngine getDatabaseConnection() {
        ....
    }
}
```

2. Second, create files let say xml files which will contains your SQL
   and according to your DB (which can be configured) these files will
   be converted to its SQL

---

Example:

> ***SQL file:*** customer.table

```
<TABLE>
    <SELECT>
        <FROM>customer</FROM>
        <WHERE>customer_id = ?</WHERE>
        <ORDER_BY>customer_id<ORDER_BY>
    </SELECT>
</TABLE>
```

Now if your configuration file says your database is oracle, then while compiling above SQL file it will create following SQL file:

```
SELECT * FROM customer
 WHERE customer_id = ?
 ORDER BY customer_id
```